# jQuery - Animation transition interrupted by hover

Tags: jquery, animation

I have created a div to slide in from outside of the viewport and place itself over the original div.

The animation is triggered by hovering over `box1`. This will bring `box2` in place of `box1`.

When the mouse leaves the `box2` div, it will be placed outside of the viewport again.

However, slow cursor movement within this div will result in animation triggering rapidly.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.box1').mouseover(function() {
    $('.box2').stop().animate({
        top: 0
    }, 100);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('.box2').stop().animate({
        top: '-200px'
    }, 100);
});
});
```

The following fiddle should present the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/B9wx8/

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish but good counteraction for `.mouseout()` is `.mouseenter()`, not `.mouseover()`.

Comment: The animation almost works as intended. But the problem is that slow mouse movement within the div will trigger the animation rapidly to create a jerky animation.

Comment: If your problem is that the animation isn't complete, it's probably because when you run it, `box2` will appear under your cursor and `.mouseout()` is triggered. You could bypass that problem by using `.mousemove()` where you have mouse position available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, Bind event for both elements, it would solve the issue

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box1,.box2').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.box2').stop().animate({
            top: 0
        }, 'slow');
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $('.box2').stop().animate({
            top: '-200px'
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B9wx8/30/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var done = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box1').mouseenter(function() {
        if (done){
            done = false;
            $('.box2').stop().animate({
                top: 0
            }, {duration: 400,
                complete: 
                    function(){
                        done = true
                    }
                 });
        }
    });
    $('.box2').mouseleave(function() {
        if (done){            
            done = false;
            $('.box2').stop().animate({
                top: -400
            }, {duration: 400,
                complete: 
                    function(){
                        done = true
                    }
                 });
        }
    });
});
```

So check if the animation is still going, and only if not start the next one